# Change Web service WSDL namespace s to xs

Tags: c#, web-services, soap, wsdl

I wrote web service in Visual Studio 2017 (File->New->Web Site->ASP.NET Empty Web Site->Web Service (ASMX) in Visual C#)

when I publish the

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://smp.ws.uz/", Name = "SMP034")]

public class ReceivePayment : WebService
{
    [WebMethod]
    [return: XmlElement("accept")]
    [SoapDocumentMethod(ParameterStyle = SoapParameterStyle.Wrapped)]
    public accept receivePayment(payment payment)
    {
        accept accept = new accept();
        ....
        set all properties of accept object some value
        ....
        return accept;
    }
}
```

When I publish this web service I get WSDL like below:

```
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" .....>
```

with **s** namespace, but I need this as **xs** namespace.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: This is a namespace *alias*; it shouldn't make any difference to any compliant parser (as long as the alias is used correctly in the body), since the alias is not part of the schema specification (it is a part of the payload)

Comment: Is there a way to change the namespace alias for my case?